# Почему при автоинкременте происходит пропуск Id?

Tags: mysql

После добавления оказалось, что в поле поля id с включенным автоинкрементом, имеется пропуск одного значения Id в двух местах таблицы.

Это не критично, но возникает вопрос: Как это возможно?

Перед добавлением записей, таблица была очищена и автоинкемент был приведен к значению 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Я вижу два варианта.

- запись была удалена
- попытка insert операции без сохранения. почитайте

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: 1. Я делаю только операции select и insert.
2. В запросах я использую autocommit

Comment: Хоть два автокоммит. Это тоже может не сработать по определённым причинам, и номер id пропадёт.

Comment: Еще вариантик - триггер.

Comment: @TotalPusher триггеров нет

Comment: @danilshik, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582704/auto-increment-primary-leaving-gaps-in-counting

Comment: @MaxU ответ был направлен на транзакции?

Comment: @danilshik, тут перечислены все основные причины. Хотите найти реальную причину - включите генерал лог, затем смотрите какие запросы были в проблемном промежутке.

Comment: @danilshik,  у вас запись в таблицу идёт одним потоком/пользователем или могут быть конкуретные транзакции?

Comment: Запись идет в несколько потоков.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @Denys Siebov ещё одним вариантом:

2+ пользователя (или потока) одновременно добавляют записи в таблицу. В этом случае может возникнуть ситуация когда до `commit` оба пользователя получили два последовательных `id`. По какой-то причине (нарушение уникального ключа, нарушение `CHECK constraint`, и т.д.) одна из транзакций тихо откатилась. `AUTOINCREMENT` cчетчик назад не откатывается - в итоге у вас дырка в последовательности.

NOTE: `AUTO_INCREMENT` не гарантирует непрерывную последовательность генерируемых `ID`. В случае репликации дырки также могут возникать по "внутренним" для MySQL причинам.

Comment: имеется групповой индекс на два поля, при вставке таких же значений, выкидывает ошибку, и парсинг продолжается. Это происходит в 1 поток. Как я понял, из-за этого идет пропуск id. С этим как нибудь можно бороться?

Comment: @danilshik, что значит бороться? Обрабатывайте ошибку так как вам надо. Как вам уже неоднократно объяснили MySQL не умеет гарантировать последовательность без дыр при использовании `AUTO_INCREMENT`...

Comment: я хотел спросить что можно сделать. Может операцию в транзакцию добавить и в случае неудачи, откатить изменения?